# Does "I will send you a product manual." sound natural if it is a message written in an email with the product manual already attached?

Tags: tense

The other day, I received an email saying "*I will send you a product manual. Please read it carefully.*" The manual mentioned was attached to the email.

I'm curious to know if that expression is natural or not. This is because I felt from the email message as if the sender of the email was going to send me the product manual sometime in the future after the email. I thought it should have been said like the following examples.

e.g.

- I attached a product manual.
- I have attached a product manual.
- I'm sending you a product manual.

Am I wrong?

Comment: The answers by Seowjooheng Singapore and the-baby-is-you can equally be the best answer. I simply chose one of them based on the number of the "usefulness" count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I attached a product manual.
> I have attached a product manual.
> I'm sending you a product manual.

You are right to doubt the original expression.

Your suggested improvements are grammatical, but the last 2 are better.

The 1st one is in past tense, but the emailing is happening now.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, that's unnatural and misleading. You'd most often hear "I've/I have attached X" or some version of "X is attached*", but any of your examples would be fine.

*To be a little more specific, you might hear the unusual syntax "Attached are X, Y, and Z" if the description of what's attached is longer than a few words, for a more readable sentence flow.